# R: two way ANOVA and ANCOVA functions return same result: is the code wrong?

Tags: r, anova

I am struggling to find the right code for an analysis of covariance (ANCOVA) that is different from a 2 way anova that includes interactions. Here are the steps I followed:

The goal here is to compare the speed of 4 groups of skiers.

My one way ANOVA would be

```
summary(aov(speed~group,data=df))
```

Then I wanted to see if another way of grouping had an effect: the gender of skiers. I therefore performed a two way ANOVA

```
summary(aov(speed~group+gender,data=df))
```

I then read on several websites (like [this page on sthda](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/two-way-anova-test-in-r)) that we could check the interaction of these two categorial variables with this code

```
summary(aov(speed~group*gender,data=df))
```

Then I heard about ANCOVA and found on the rare websites talking about it on R that the code was the same as above:

```
summary(aov(speed~group*gender,data=df))
```

So here is my question: have I misunderstood something in the tests or the code above or can we simply say that an ANCOVA and a two way ANOVA including interaction are the same?

Thank you all a lot in advance for your comments and thoughts

Comment: consider ANCOVA is a generalization of ANOVA, if your model is simple, they are the same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ANOVA and ANCOVA are both names for special cases of [multiple linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) (and typically, subsequent F tests for explained variance between nested models).

If all your variables are [categorical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_variable), you have an ANOVA. (The underlying regression typically uses dummy coding, but that does not matter for the F test.)

If some of your variables are numerical (but you typically *also* have categorical variables, which you are mainly interested in), you have an ANCOVA.

The mathematics going on "under the hood" are precisely identical.

This nomenclature confused me at first, too. And I'm a mathematician. It would have been far easier to immediately see the regression equations, rather than complicated explanations involving different arguments for two special cases.

Comment: Thank you immensely for such a clear answer ! :-)